# Unable to upload artifacts into JFrog Artifactory because of unrecognized field

Tags: maven, artifactory

Unable to upload artifacts into JFrog Artifactory cloud, all of a sudden. Note: gradle and maven plugin both fail

```
    id 'com.jfrog.artifactory' version '4.21.0'

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jfrog.buildinfo</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifactory-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
....
            </plugin>

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "slf" (class org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryUploadResponse), not marked as ignorable (12 known properties: "checksums", "size", "repo", "downloadUri", "path", "statusLine", "created", "errors", "uri", "mimeType", "createdBy", "originalChecksums"])
```

Refer https://pastebin.com/AyBqfJ7Y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven Artifactory plugin 3.2.3 is recently released. This version includes a fix for this issue.

The root cause is a new field returned from Artifactory in the response of the upload REST API.
The fix is to ignore new unknown fields instead of throwing the `UnrecognizedPropertyException`.

For more information see https://github.com/jfrog/build-info/pull/502.

Comment: @yahavi - is there a gradle plugin fix as well? I am getting the same error while using the gradle plugin. thanks

Comment: @mesh Yes. Please use the latest version 4.24.14. See release notes here: https://github.com/jfrog/build-info/blob/master/RELEASE.md